# How do i convert an array of objects into 1 object in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects like this:

```
myArray = [
    {itemOneKey: 'itemOneValue', itemTwoKey: 'itemTwoValue'},
    {itemThreeKey: 'itemThreeValue'}
];
```

I wish to turn it to a single object like this:

```
myObject = {
    itemOneKey: 'itemOneValue',
    itemTwoKey: 'itemTwoValue',
    itemThreeKey: 'itemThreeValue'
}
```

in TypeScript. Anyone have a clue how I can go about to achieve this?

Comment: Note that if keys are repeated in the objects in your array (like if two objects have a property "itemKey"), then the result object will have only one value for that key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to merge all the objects.

```js
const myArray = [
    {itemOneKey: 'itemOneValue', itemTwoKey: 'itemTwoValue'},
    {itemThreeKey: 'itemThreeValue'}
];
const res = Object.assign({}, ...myArray);
console.log(res);
```